# Link two convergent sequences to a diverging one

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Are there two sequences that, even though they converge to a value in R including $\infty$ and $- \infty$, result in a diverging sequence when added and multiplied? I've been searching for a while now and didn't find any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you allow "convergence" towards $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, and you want their sum and product not to converge even towards $+\infty$ or $-\infty$? Do you want _one_ pair of sequences such that _neither_ sum nor product converges, or just an example for sum and one for product?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, exactly, neither of them should converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ converge (possibly to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$), then at least one of $(a_n+b_n)$ or $(a_nb_n)$ will converge likewise.

More precisely, the only combination of limits that *won't* automatically make $(a_n+b_n)$ converge is if one of the original sequences converge to $+\infty$ and the other to $-\infty$. But then $(a_nb_n)$ will necessarily go towards $-\infty$.